# Geting the SSID and IP address of connecting device(before connecting need to get permission) to Android hotspot(Wifi-tethering)

Tags: android

I like to get the SSID and IP adress of devices trying to connect my hoptspot. Is there any way that i can check them and give permission.

Answer (score -1):

yes its possible you should register you broadcast receiver inside of activity like this

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {


@Override
  public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    List<ScanResult> results = wifiDemo.wifi.getScanResults();
    ScanResult bestSignal = null;
 final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
    System.out.println("booladsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
  }
    for (ScanResult result : results) {
      if (bestSignal == null
          || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level, result.level) < 0)
        bestSignal = result;
    }

    String message = String.format("%s networks found. %s is the strongest.",
        results.size(), bestSignal.SSID);
    Toast.makeText(wifiDemo, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() message: " + message);
  }
```

and you should put all this the permission to your manifest files ..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

its perfectly worked for me. if you have ant doubt kindly post you comment .. thank you

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I like to know how I can grant permission for the users that scanreult will return. I dont want few users to login to my hotspot. If I see theier name I need to block them from access my hotspot.

Comment: i checked the above code, its only giving my own wifi connection state change but not getting any response if the client connect to the hotspot.... please give any suggestions.

Comment: @ShyamDev it will be showing all the available wifi ssid only after that you should write code for permission and allowing them to connect you hotspot ..first you should mark this as a answer....

Comment: moorthy I am using a Tethering network where the above code will not return the IP address since in tethering the normal wifi activities will be disabled hence it returns 0.0.0.0 Ip address. Thats why I didnt mark this answer but it will work in normal network.

Comment: But I got the answer for the above post, we need to search the Ip address of clients from arp cache. But  my next coding is for disconnecting a particular user from mt hotspot. If you have any suggestion please help me. Remember that it is  tethered network hence few functionality in wifi manager or confiuration will not work

Comment: @ShyamDev if you know that user SSID? if so ignore that user SSID. when it will be connected..

Comment: to ignore the SSID I am unable to find the suitable method in Hotspot mode (tethering). I am still searching for that class to handle my client. If you got any idea or name of methods please tell me, I will research on it.