# Monitoring the Hotspot state in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm new to android.
I want to receive information via `broadcastreceiver` (`onReceive`) to know that if user enable/disable `"Portable Wi-Fi Hotspot"` `(Settings->Wireless &Networks->Tethering & portable hotspot)`.
Check this [link](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#132)
And I found that there is "`android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED`" but it was set to hidden. Any how I can use that ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

to receive enable/disable "Portable Wi-Fi Hotspot" events you will need to register an Receiver  for WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED as :

```
mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
```

inside BroadcastReceiver onReceive we can extract wifi Hotspot state using `wifi_state` as :

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if ("android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED".equals(action)) {

             // get Wi-Fi Hotspot state here 
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, 0);

            if (WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED == state % 10) {
                // Wifi is enabled
            }

        }
    }
};
```

you can do same by declaring Receiver in AndroidManifest for `android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED` action  and also include all necessary wifi permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`

**EDIT :**

Add receiver in AndroidManifest as :

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiApmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

you can see [this](https://github.com/classicnerd/android_packages_apps_CNWidgets/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) example for more help

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. But could you show me how to declare in android manifest since it's easier to understand.

Comment: Already add in your code and it errors out "The method getIntExtra in the Type intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)".

Comment: @TrisNguyen : check my edit answer and pass any default integer value

Comment: @TrisNguyen : and u can also use `int state = intent.getInt("wifi_state");` instead of `int state = intent.getIntExtra("wifi_state", 
                                    0);`

Comment: Sorry for the silly question. But I guess whenever activating the hotspot android. The value of variable "state" is changed, am i correct ?? And change to what value ??

Comment: @TrisNguyen :this will return u 0,1 and  best way is just make a log and check what value it's returning .

Comment: Thanks alot for your support !!! I will give it a try !!! I'm still really new to this. Could you give me your email. My email is:nguyentri.it@gmail.com . Thanks for you knowledge !!!

Comment: @TrisNguyen : you can also see [this](http://easy-profile-change.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/easy-profile-change/src/de/pepping/android/ringtone/handler/WifiHopspotSettingHandler.java) example

Comment: Just wanna say thank you alot...I managed to get it work ! Thanks for the help

Comment: wifi_state received from intent.getIntExtra("wifi_state", 0) has values in the range 10-13. These values are outside the wifi_state values define in WifiManager Class here- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html. How do we know when wifi hotspot is enabled or disabled? More precisely, what wifi_state value should we check for to get this information?

Comment: @user802467 you can use `if (WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED == state % 10)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it works!, the only thing is the receiver gets called twice, but I will find a workaround for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Hii #user802467 there is answer to your question asked in comment at this link : [How to get wifi hotspot state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841421/how-to-get-wifi-hotspot-state). Values are between 10-13 because of version 4 and above. You can easily get the actual state as explained in the link.