# How can i check my android device is in Access Point mode?

Tags: android, access-point

I know how to get Access Point configuration like this:

```
public static WifiConfiguration getAccessPointWifiConfiguration() {
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) App.get().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Method[] methods = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m: methods) {
        if (m.getName().equals("getWifiApConfiguration")) {
            try {
                return (WifiConfiguration) m.invoke(wifimanager);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can i check i'm current in AP mode since configuration can exist but it should be enabled.

PS. Seems to be what i need [How to get wifi hotspot state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841421/how-to-get-wifi-hotspot-state)